# Finding if string vector contains any string from other vector

Tags: r, text

Is there a simple way to find if a string vector contains specific any string from other vector? 
I have a database of mail addresses, and need to select only those from specific publishers (list ot around 100)

```
Mail <- c("xxx1@xxx.xx", "xxx2@xxx.xx", "xxx3@yyy.xx", "xxx4@zzz.xx")
InterestingPublishers <- c("zzz.xx", "xxx.xx")
```

I have tried using %in%, but that checked for whole fazes:

```
Mail  %in% InterestingPublishers 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Also grepl and grep did not help because I cannot put vector as an input:

```
grepl(InterestingPublishers, Mail)
Warning message:
In grepl(InterestingPublishers, Mail) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: `Mail[unlist(sapply(InterestingPublishers, function(x) which(grepl(x, Mail))))]`

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_detect(Mail, regex = paste(InterestingPublishers, collapse="|"))`

Comment: Just `sub('.*@', '', Mail) %in% InterestingPublishers`

Comment: @Sotos You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are interested in the domain. In this case I d suggest to remove everything but the domain and top level domain and simply use `%in%`, i.e.

```
sub('.*@', '', Mail) %in% InterestingPublishers
```

Answer (score 1):

While `d.b`'s answer (currently in the comments) is perfectly reasonable here is another base-`R` solution using loops (which tend to be slower but can be more transparent for beginners):

```
containsi <- integer()
for (i in InterestingPublishers) {
  containsi <- c(containsi, grep(i, Mail))
}
Mail[containsi]

[1] "xxx4@zzz.xx" "xxx1@xxx.xx" "xxx2@xxx.xx"
```

PS. you might get [a slight speed improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761541/why-is-unlistlapply-faster-than-sapply) (if that matters) by using `lapply` instead of `sapply` in `d.b`'s solution.

```
Mail[unlist(lapply(InterestingPublishers, function(x) grep(x, Mail)))]
```