# R: sapply / lapply Different Behaviour with Names

Tags: r

I reduced some problem to the following toy code:

```
cc<-c("1","2")
ff<-function(x) { list(myname=x)}

aa<-unlist(lapply(cc,ff))
bb<-sapply(cc,ff)
```

[I'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761541/why-is-unlistlapply-faster-than-sapply) aa and bb to be identical, but:

```
> aa
myname myname 
   "1"    "2" 
> bb
$`1.myname`
[1] "1"

$`2.myname`
[1] "2"
```

I'm aware of the USE.NAMES argument to sapply, however -

1. it's [documented](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.99.22/topics/Sapply) as -

> USE.NAMES  logical; if TRUE and if X is character, use X as names for
> the result **unless it had names already**.

and so should have no impact in this case,

2. Internally, it isn't even passed to simplify2array and thus neither to the final unlist.

What's going on here? Could this be an R issue?

---

Edit: after further investigation it turns out the root cause for the difference is that sapply is essentially equivalent not to

`unlist(lapply(cc,ff)`

but rather to

`unlist(lapply(cc, ff), recursive = FALSE)`

(This is the exact internal unlist call).

Comment: but `cc` doesn't have names hence why they are added

Comment: @user20650 ff adds the name.

Comment: I took the *it* in "unless it had names" to be *X* the input not the result but on re-reading I may be mistaken

Comment: ... (as it what happens here `names(cc) = c("A", "B"); sapply(cc,ff)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at this:

```
lapply(cc, ff)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$myname
#> [1] "1"
#>
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$myname
#> [1] "2"
```

The output of `lapply` itself doesn't have names. Look:

```
a <- lapply(cc, ff)
names(a)
#> NULL
```

The output of the `lapply` is actually an *unnamed list*. Each *element* of `a` is a *named list*.

```
names(a[[1]])
#> [1] "myname"
names(a[[2]])
#> [1] "myname"
```

So in fact, `USE.NAMES` will apply, and `sapply` will assign the contents of `cc` as names for the output of the `lapply` for which `sapply` is a thin wrapper as stated in the documentation. It's quite straightforward to follow the code through:

```
sapply
#> function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
#> {
#>     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#>     answer <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
#>     if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
#>         names(answer) <- X
#>     if (!isFALSE(simplify) && length(answer)) 
#>         simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
#>     else answer
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x036ae7a8>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: thanks, but note that somehow sapply *concatenates* the pre existing names and cc’s contents. I’m not sure whether that’s intended behaviour.

Comment: @OfekShilon it *is* the intended behaviour. It concatentates the names because once it adds the names to the top level list, it simplifies the nested list into a single layer. When it does this it concatenates the names of the first and second layers. Try `unlist(list(a = list(b = 1), c = list(d = 1)))` to see what I mean

Comment: Ahh, thanks.   And why the difference in class()?  simplify2array is essentially a wrapper around unlist.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, but please note the additional info I added to the question.

Comment: @OfekShilon thank you, and thanks for the extra information.